# List multiple rows by 30 minute intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2014 Query - Windows

I have records where the start and end time span multiple 30 minute intervals.  I would like the results to have a separate row for each 30 minute interval.  So when the start time is 2:01:37 and the end time is 05:00:21, I would want to see rows for the following intervals:  02:00:00, 02:30:00, 03:00:00, 03:30:00, 04:00:00, 04:30:00, 05:00:00.  I would want to see display the start and end times in each row so I could do calculations to determine elapsed time per interval.  For most of these intervals, elapsed time in seconds would be 1800.  The first and last interval would be less.

I've tried some of the links here and didn't find what I was looking for.  I appreciate any help you can offer.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Which DB are you using? Add the tag [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50217288/edit) your question. Over which OS? Whatś the desired destination for your query? A file? A service? Please add to your question the attempts you did (a relevant one) alongside with the errors you found.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE to generate your intervals. You can follow this example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SuppliedIntervals') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SuppliedIntervals

CREATE TABLE #SuppliedIntervals (
    StartInterval DATETIME,
    EndInterval DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #SuppliedIntervals (
    StartInterval,
    EndInterval)
VALUES
    ('2018-04-22 02:00:00.000', '2018-04-22 05:00:00.000'),
    ('2018-04-22 19:30:00.000', '2018-04-22 20:30:00.000')

;WITH RecursiveIntervalCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        T.StartInterval,
        T.EndInterval,
        GeneratedInterval = T.StartInterval
    FROM
        #SuppliedIntervals AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        R.StartInterval,
        R.EndInterval,
        GeneratedInterval = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, R.GeneratedInterval)
    FROM
        RecursiveIntervalCTE AS R
    WHERE
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, R.GeneratedInterval) <= R.EndInterval
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    RecursiveIntervalCTE AS R
ORDER BY
    R.StartInterval,
    R.GeneratedInterval

/*
Results:

    StartInterval           EndInterval             GeneratedInterval
    ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 02:00:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 02:30:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 03:00:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 03:30:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 04:00:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 04:30:00.000
    2018-04-22 02:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000 2018-04-22 05:00:00.000

    2018-04-22 19:30:00.000 2018-04-22 20:30:00.000 2018-04-22 19:30:00.000
    2018-04-22 19:30:00.000 2018-04-22 20:30:00.000 2018-04-22 20:00:00.000
    2018-04-22 19:30:00.000 2018-04-22 20:30:00.000 2018-04-22 20:30:00.000

*/
```